# R data.table filtering on group size

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to find all the records in my `data.table` for which there is more than one row with value *v* in field *f*.

For instance, we can use this data:

```
dt <- data.table(f1=c(1,2,3,4,5), f2=c(1,1,2,3,3))
```

If looking for that property in field `f2`, we'd get (note the absence of the (3,2) tuple)

```
    f1 f2
1:  1  1
2:  2  1
3:  4  3
4:  5  3
```

My first guess was `dt[.N>2,list(.N),by=f2]`, but that actually keeps entries with `.N==1`.

```
dt[.N>2,list(.N),by=f2]
   f2 N
1:  1 2
2:  2 1
3:  3 2
```

The other easy guess, `dt[duplicated(dt$f2)]`, doesn't do the trick, as it keeps one of the 'duplicates' out of the results.

```
dt[duplicated(dt$f2)]
   f1 f2
1:  2  1
2:  5  3
```

So how can I get this done?

**Edited to add example**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is not clear.  Based on the title, it looks like we want to extract all groups with number of rows (`.N`) greater than 1.

```
DT[, if(.N>1) .SD, by=f]
```

But the `value v in field f` is making it confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you'll need to do some compound queries:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(v1 = 1:10, f = c(rep(1:3, 3), 4))
DT[, N := .N, f][N > 2][, N := NULL][]
#    v1 f
# 1:  1 1
# 2:  2 2
# 3:  3 3
# 4:  4 1
# 5:  5 2
# 6:  6 3
# 7:  7 1
# 8:  8 2
# 9:  9 3
```